# what should be the powershell \ portal \ cli commands to see what are the current permissions for a certain blob

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-cli, azureportal

I have created a URI based access to a certain blob on azure blob storage and wish to close this access. Is there a command line code anything to manage it?

Comment: URI based access means it uses sas token? and what's the meaning of "close this access"?

Answer (score 0):

Assume "URI based access to a certain blob" means that you generate a [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#types-of-shared-access-signatures) and append to the blob endpoint, like this: https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/test1/metrics.PNG?sp=r&st=2019-09-13T01:38:08Z&se=2019-09-13T09:38:08Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=xxxx.

Then in the url, you can see the permissions in "sp=r", "r" means read access for the blob.

Regarding how to close this access if it's based on sas token, it depends on how to generate the sas token as below:

1.If the sas token is NOT associated with a [stored access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/define-stored-access-policy), the only way is that regenerate the account key. This way will affect other applications who use the storage account.

2.If the sas token is associated with a [stored access policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/define-stored-access-policy), then you can just modify the stored access policy like modify the expired date etc.

Please let me know if you have any other issues.